# React-Hook-Form Validation

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm looking to implement the form validation using react-hook. However, I'm facing some trouble in doing so as I've also added some stuff on my own under the handleSubmit and I'm not really sure how to go about it.

```
export default function Contact() {
const [message, setMessage] = useState(false);
const [alert, setAlert] = useState(true);


const { register, errors} = useForm();
const [showElement, setShowElement] = React.useState(false);
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  emailjs.sendForm('', '', e.target, '')
  .then((result) => {
      console.log(result.text);
  }, (error) => {
      console.log(error.text);
  });
  e.target.reset();
  setMessage(true);
  setShowElement(true);
  setTimeout(function () {
    setShowElement(false);
  }, 4000);
};

const onSubmit= data=>{
  console.log(data);
}


return (
    <div className="right">
      <h2>Contact Me</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="contactform">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" ref={register({required: true, minLength: 2})}
         required />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
      {showElement ? (
        <div className="submitmsg">
          {message && (
            <span> Messaged received. I'll respond to your query ASAP! </span>
          )}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div> </div>
      )}{" "}
    </div>
 )
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you specify the issue you are facing?

Comment: You are missing `const { handleSubmit } = useForm();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React hook form provides the [handeSubmit](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/handlesubmit) method that receives the form data after validations. Also, you must use the errors object to show errors in the UI.

Here is the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-dust-df5ft?file=/src/App.js

I have updated your code accordingly:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import React from "react";
import emailjs from "emailjs-com";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function Contact() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(false);
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();
  const [showElement, setShowElement] = React.useState(false);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    emailjs
      .send(
        "service_t1ccrgq",
        "template_gmmcyzr",
        data,
        "user_d0vUwhmqvbIYhEsyZF8tu"
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
    setMessage(true);
    setShowElement(true);
    setTimeout(function () {
      setShowElement(false);
    }, 4000);
  };

  return (
    <div className="contact" id="contact">
      <div className="left">
        <img className="contactme" src="asset/email.gif" />
      </div>

      <div className="right">
        <h2>Contact Me</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} id="contactform">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
            name="name"
            {...register("name", {
              required: "Name is Required",
              minLength: {
                value: 3,
                message: "Should be greater than 3 characters"
              }
            })}
          />
          <input
            type="tel"
            placeholder="Mobile Number"
            name="mobile"
            {...register("mobile", {
              required: "Mobile Number is Required",
              minLength: {
                value: 3,
                message: "Should be greater than 3 characters"
              }
            })}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Email"
            name="email"
            {...register("email", {
              required: "Email is Required",
              minLength: {
                value: 3,
                message: "Should be greater than 3 characters"
              }
            })}
          />
          <textarea
            placeholder="Message"
            required
            name="message"
            {...register("message", {
              required: "Message is Required",
              minLength: {
                value: 3,
                message: "Should be greater than 3 characters"
              }
            })}
          ></textarea>
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
        {showElement ? (
          <div className="submitmsg">
            {message && (
              <span> Messaged received. I'll respond to your query ASAP! </span>
            )}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div> </div>
        )}{" "}
      </div>
      {errors.name && (
        <div>
          <span>{errors.name.message}</span>
        </div>
      )}
      {errors.message && (
        <div>
          <span>{errors.message.message}</span>
        </div>
      )}
      {errors.email && (
        <div>
          <span>{errors.email.message}</span>
        </div>
      )}
      {errors.mobile && (
        <div>
          <span>{errors.mobile.message}</span>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, but my code that is supposed to run after clicking submit doesn't work already. There's suppose to be a message that appears and the input is supposed to be sent using emailjs. It works previously

Comment: what do you need to send to emailjs? the submit method takes the form data inside the data argument.

Comment: it's supposed to send the details from the form to my email, it works previously. In addition, there's suppose to be a message that appears: Messaged received. I'll respond to your query ASAP! 

But none of this is happening anymore

Comment: Did you replace your code completely with mine? I see that you have an existing onSubmit method in your previous code. You need to get rid of that

Comment: Yup I did, I've created a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-voice-whg02?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i have updated my answer now. You need to use emailjs.send instead of emailjs.sendForm. Kindly look at the answer and accept it if it works for you.

Comment: Hmm, I only seem to be receiving input from the email field

Comment: Can I check, why did you use emailjs.send instead of sendForm? technically i can receive the form, but only the input from the email field is appearing

Comment: yes, because I did not complete the code. I thought you understood. You literally had me coded the entire thing now. I have updated my answer as well as the sandbox link. Have fun! Everything is working now from error handling to sending data correctly

Comment: ah ok, my bad. I didn't include the {..register} for the other fields.. Sorry about it

Comment: I have also added the error handling for you. Please accept the answer so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first initialize handleSubmit as below.

```
const {handleSubmit} = useForm();
```

Then in the form, onSubmit should be as below.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```

"onSubmit" is the method that is used to write the code in submitting form.
Regards.
In your code, it should be as below.

```
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      emailjs.sendForm('', '', e.target, '')
      .then((result) => {
      console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
      console.log(error.text);
      });
      e.target.reset();
      setMessage(true);
      setShowElement(true);
      setTimeout(function () {
      setShowElement(false);
     }, 4000);
 };
```

Comment: Ah ok, but my code that is supposed to run after clicking submit doesn't work already. 
There's suppose to be a message that appears and the input is supposed to be sent using emailjs. It works previously